# R version of matlab gausswin function

Tags: r, matlab

I am looking for a way to replicate the matlab function [gausswin](http://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/gausswin.html):

> w = gausswin(N,Alpha) returns an N-point Gaussian window with Alpha proportional to the reciprocal of the standard deviation. The width of the window is inversely related to the value of α. A larger value of α produces a more narrow window.

Is there an existing base function or package which already exists?

Comment: `install.packages("sos", dependencies=TRUE); library(sos); findFn("gausswin")` Have fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pascal’s comment I found the package `signal` which contains a collection of windowing functions (And also one called `gausswin`).

Comment: Then why not accepted Pascal's answer and edit it to include your final anwser...

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest way to find a function in R is to use the `sos` library.

```
# install the library
install.packages("sos", dependencies=TRUE)

# load the library
library(sos)

# search the desired function using its name or some keywords
findFn("gausswin")
# found 3 matches
# Downloaded 3 links in 1 packages.
```